# VPN Client-Client connection between sites

Tags: vpn, openvpn, site-to-site-vpn

At our company, having multiple physical locations, we currently utilize an OpenVPN solution faciliated by a server at our main office. All sub-sites connect to this server, interconnecting the office networks of the sub-sites and main office.

Is it possible to setup OpenVPN or run a similar service, where sub-site to sub-site traffic, is routed directly between the sub-sites instead of via the main office router?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is certainly possible, provided that the IP subnets are separate in each office.

All you need is a public IP address on either office you want to connect, and then add VPN server there. The other office connects to this VPN server.

Then you need to set up routes on both ends so that traffic for the other office is sent via the VPN link.

This is a general descriptions how it works. Details on network set up dictate how the eventual configuration will look like.